# Valid OAuth redirect URIs for Facebook app login

Tags: facebook, oauth, uri

I'm trying to find out the correct `redirect_uri` for my facebook's login, but no matter what I do, it still doesn't work.

Here is the error output:

> URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the
>   client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as
>   valid OAuth redirect URIs.

Here is my FB's [login URL](http://%20https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=1813905928716994&state=4b1fa2d59c26d348e2f24cd83aa0c920&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.6.2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.boogla.com%2Fjoin_facebook.php%3Fcmd%3Dfb_login&scope=email)

[These are my FB app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgmSh.png)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: And the exact value of the redirect_uri parameter in that login URL is  `https://www.boogla.com/join_facebook.php?cmd=fb_login`

Answer (score 1):

You should try following for the redirect url.

Your redirect URI will typically have the format https://engage-appname.rpxnow.com/facebook/callback.

For example, if your Engage app has the name `my--test-app`, your redirect URI would be https://my-test-app.rpxnow.com/facebook/callback.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me...
I have added this in client OAuth settings:

Embedded Browser OAuth Login:Yes

Valid OAuth Redirect URIs:
https://abc.pythonanywhere.com(or your site)/accounts/facebook/login/callback/

Note: before to add this above url in Valid OAuth Redirct URIs
got to

In settings-->Advanced

Share Redirect Allow List:

add this url in Share Redirect Domain Allow list:

https://abc.pythonanywhere.com(or your site)/accounts/facebook/login/callback/

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you try this in your Basic settings->Site URL:**

```
https://yoursite.com/signin-facebook
```

**and in your Basic settings->App Domain:**

```
yoursite.com
```